# Unable to generate a key with GnuPG (agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory)

Tags: gnupg

When running `gpg --gen-key`, I get:

```
gpg: agent_genkey failed: No such file or directory
Key generation failed: No such file or directory
```

I tried `killall gpg-agent` and `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`. My `private-keys-v1.d` is created, within `~/.gnupg`.

I am also not able to delete secret keys:

```
gpg: deleting secret key failed: No such file or directory
gpg: deleting secret subkey failed: No such file or directory
```

EDIT:

I tried removing .gnupg and reinstalling gpg, still having the issue.

Comment: I bypassed this issue by using `pinentry-mac` instead of `pinentry`

Answer (score 4):

The problem for me was that I set `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in the shell.

The reason was to fix this error

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

After I removed it worked properly.

Answer (score 2):

The directory `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` may under some circumstances
not be created or perhaps created with the wrong permissions.

Try this:

```
# mkdir -p ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
# chmod 700 ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
```

Look also for any strange files in the `.gnupg` directory that
may need to be deleted.

Comment: This directory exists and has the correct permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The terminal emulator you're using is certainly not a tty. `pinentry-tty` is the default for entering passphrase. It works for me by changing it to `pinentry-gnome3`. To see pinentry which you can use : `ls /usr/bin | grep pinentry`.

You need to add this line in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/<pinentry_name>
```

and reload the `gpg-connect-agent`

```bash
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `sudo gpg --gen-key` and it worked for me